# quickstep recent button stopped working with new launcher, is there way to edit recent button source code in android studio?

Tags: adb

Whenever I try to use recent button in a newly installed launcher, I get error, 'quickstep keeps stopping'.i want to edit quickstep settings in Android studio to make recent button work with any launcher, could this be done?